# After download rename source file in php

Tags: php

I loop .jpg file from my uploads/document and show it in my page and then i click to download one by one file and after I download .jpg from source in folder uploads\document\ the real file from my folder will be rename to other name.

I try these:

```
<?php
foreach (glob('uploads/document/' . '/*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
    echo '<a class="snapchat" download="' . basename($file)  . '" href="/uploads/document' . '/' . basename($file) . '">' . basename($file) .
        '</a><br/>';

        rename('/uploads/document' . '/' . basename($file) ,'Mynew' );

}
?>
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so what are they?

Comment: @Jordy: Warning: rename(/uploads/document/Announcement.jpg,Mynew): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

Comment: That is not going to work because when the browser parses the html and downloads the image, this same image is already renamed. You to rename first and then echo the `<a...` with the nem file name

Comment: @claudio So you mean we cannot rename the source file after download?

Comment: @TheRock I'm saying that if you rename the file after you print the link to the original image and the rename, when you click the link the original image doesn't exists anymore

Comment: @claudio: i loop .jpg file from my uploads/document and then i click to download one file i want that file in source file rename

Comment: Why do you want that? Do you want the user to get a `Mynew.jpg` when they download?

Comment: @Jordy: No i want my source file change to Mynew.jpg

Comment: @Jordy Please look my update question

Comment: Like @claudio "you cannot rename the source file before download" so you can use another php script to handle the download

Comment: @MohamedSa'ed yes thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** : you cannot rename the source file before download , so you need to rename it after download

You **can** do that by `PHP header() Function`  all you need is another php script to **handle** the download and **rename** the file,
**Like :**

1- Main PHP

```
<?php
$dir = 'files/';//uploads/document/
foreach (glob("$dir*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
    echo '<a class="snapchat" download="'.basename($file).'" href="download.php?fn='.basename($file).'">'.basename($file).'</a><br/>';
}
?>
```

2 - download.php

```
<?php
$dir = 'files/';//uploads/document/
$file = $dir.$_GET['fn'];
if (file_exists($file))
{
    $type = 'image/jpeg';
    header('Content-Type:'.$type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    rename($file, $dir."mynewName");
    exit();
}
else // file not exists Or has been downloaded before
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');/* Retern Forbidden */
    /*OR*/ 
    //header("Location: 404.php?".$file); /* Redirect browser */
    exit();
}
?>
```